# Why can't I use useLocation in BrowserRouter in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react app, with react-router v6 used as the routing system. I have tried several ways of listening to route changes, as I have a function to run every time, yet I couldn't manage to get it working. The code sample below, which I believe is the intended way of using the useLocation hook, runs to an error, "useLocation can only be used in the context of router, yet I believe BrowserRouter creates a router, it is even showed in the error message, yet I still can't use it. The error  can be seen in the screenshot.

```
function App() {
    const location = useLocation()
    React.useEffect(() => { console.log(location) }, [location])
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <CssBaseline />
                    <Main />
                </ThemeProvider>
        </Provider>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

[image: The error shown by the browser]

> Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a Router component.
> The above error occurred in the App component:
> in App
> in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
> in BrowserRouter

Comment: May you share what the errors actually say (as text)?

Comment: Added it in the edit

Comment: May you share a codepen, or codesandbox example of this?

Comment: I don't know if it works, I have never created a codependent before, but here https://codepen.io/szisziban/project/editor/ZBmbzd

Comment: The codepen example doesn't throw the errors you're seeing?

Comment: I couldn't really manage to import the node packages in codpen, like react router dom and react router, so that's why I do not see any error like mine

Comment: I ran the code in a codesandbox and I couldn't see the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

My guess you import `BrowserRouter` from `react-router` and it is not version 6 while `useLocation()` is imported from `react-router-dom` of version 6

Answer (score 1):

You can't use it from within the same component that puts the Router or BrowserRouter into the tree.

I had a similar problem and kept the BrowserRouter in App.js but moved the switch and routes to a separate 'Routes' component that also has uses the useLocation hook.